# cornerRadius on navigationController when using sideMenu

Tags: swift, xcode

i **scaled down** navigationController inside containerView,
now i want to set cornerRadius on navigationController

[image]

when i **don't use** navigationController, it's works fine as you can see in picture below:
[image]

what i'm done:
set cornerRaius on navigationController.view.
set cornerRaius on navigationController.navigationBar.

Comment: Did you set masksToBounds to true on the parent view?

Comment: @rs7 yes i did in view of navigationController

Comment: Set cornerRadius and masksToBounds for the container view.

Comment: @rs7 i did but not work

Comment: The shadow in the picture is suspicious. A view with a shadow cannot have its corners rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me:

[image]

You probably forgot to set `clipsToBounds` on the same view whose layer has the `cornerRadius` set, but it's hard to know, as you gave no information about what you did.

Comment: can you explain more?
on which view should i use?

Comment: i used in navigationController view but not work, even in viewController

Comment: What did I just say? You cannot have a shadow _and_ rounded corners from the same view. They are opposites.